# How to check if the user has entered or not entered data to Mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to see if the user has entered a website URL into the database with the following code. If the user did not enter their website's URL, do not display anything. If the user did enter their website, display the website.

I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
    <?php
    if (!empty($url))
    {
    echo'';
    } else { 
    echo'p>Website: <a href="<?php echo "http://","$url"; ?>" title="<?php echo "$url"; ?>"><?php echo "http://","$url"; ?></a></p>';
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: There are a number of odd things going on here.  Where is $url coming from, for a start?  I think we need to see more code - if this is it, then you're not even accessing a database O.o

Comment: the $url is coming from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the wrong order (you need to remove **!** before the empty()), you also have some errors in the echo part: the **<** is missing for the < p > tag and you are including php tags in your string.

It should read something like:

```
echo '<p>Website: <a href="http://' . $url . '" title="' . $url . '">http://' . $url . '</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

what you've got there is that you're checking if it's NOT empty (that is, there is some data), you're echoing an empty string. If it IS empty, then you're echoing it out.

Remove the `!` in the first line and you should be right.

Comment: I only get this now Website: " title="">.

Comment: in that case, the error isn't in that block of code, is earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You're simple mismatching the meaning of "!" :

```
<?php
if (!empty($url))
{
echo'p>Website: <a href="<?php echo "http://","$url"; ?>" title="<?php echo "$url"; ?>"><?php echo "http://","$url"; ?></a></p>';
} else { 
echo'';
} 
?>
```